# Rails, how to merge two constraints with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to constraint scope of attachments to current_user attachments or attachments that are not yet assigned to comment, to be able to `find` later

Attachment `has_one :comment, optional: true`

Attachment `has_one :user, through :comment`, comment - through task, task - through project

```
> user.attachments.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"attachments\".* FROM \"attachments\" INNER JOIN \"comments\" ON \"attachments\".\"comment_id\" = \"comments\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"tasks\" ON \"comments\".\"task_id\" = \"tasks\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"projects\" ON \"tasks\".\"project_id\" = \"projects\".\"id\" WHERE \"projects\".\"user_id\" = $1 ORDER BY \"comments\".\"created_at\" ASC, tasks.position"
```

How to make it work

```
> user.attachments.or(Attachment.where(comment_id: nil))
Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:order, :joins, :references]
```

I have tried

```
  without_comment = Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where(comment_id: nil).order('"comments"."created_at" ASC, tasks.position')
  user.attachments.or(without_comment)

[35] pry(#<AttachmentResource>)> without_comment.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"attachments\".* FROM \"attachments\" INNER JOIN \"comments\" ON \"comments\".\"id\" = \"attachments\".\"comment_id\" INNER JOIN \"tasks\" ON \"tasks\".\"id\" = \"comments\".\"task_id\" INNER JOIN \"projects\" ON \"projects\".\"id\" = \"tasks\".\"project_id\" WHERE \"attachments\".\"comment_id\" IS NULL ORDER BY \"comments\".\"created_at\" ASC, tasks.position"
[36] pry(#<AttachmentResource>)> user.attachments.or(without_comment)
ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:order, :joins, :references]
from /home/bjorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@ngrx-todolist/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:655:in `or!'
```

---

I want to find all current_user attachments plus attachments without owner -> no parent comment

Query `Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL', user.id)` doesnt include attachments without comment, why?

```
[10] pry(#<CommentResource>)> Attachment.all
=> [#<Attachment:0x00000008a6f3a8
  id: 1,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Attachment:0x00000008a6f268
  id: 2,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Attachment:0x00000008a6f128
  id: 3,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: nil,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:29:51 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:29:51 UTC +00:00>]
[11] pry(#<CommentResource>)> Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL', user.id).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"attachments\".* FROM \"attachments\" INNER JOIN \"comments\" ON \"comments\".\"id\" = \"attachments\".\"comment_id\" INNER JOIN \"tasks\" ON \"tasks\".\"id\" = \"comments\".\"task_id\" INNER JOIN \"projects\" ON \"projects\".\"id\" = \"tasks\".\"project_id\" WHERE (projects.user_id = 1 OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL)"
[12] pry(#<CommentResource>)> Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR attachments.comment_id IS NULL', user.id)
=> [#<Attachment:0x0000000891c7a8
  id: 1,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Attachment:0x0000000891c668
  id: 2,
  file: "attachments.rb",
  comment_id: 1,
  created_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 21 May 2017 14:18:21 UTC +00:00>]
```

Comment: so, basically you want all `user`'s `attachments` plus `user`'s `attachments` with no comments ?, is that what you want ?. If so, then with just `user.attachments` you will get all of them, even the ones with `comment_id = nil`.

Comment: Yes. No, attachment has user through comment, so, if no comment_id -> not displayed in user.attachments

Comment: I want all my attachments plus attachments without owner -> no parent comment

Comment: got it, ok, that's why doing `or` or even `merge` wont work since they're not compatible structures. You will need two queries or one with joins. The one with two queries would be something like `user.attachments.to_a + Attachment.where(comment_id: nil).to_a`, that's gonna give you an array of both results. The other way would require a more complex `JOIN`. Let me know if this option works for you.

Comment: I have tried it ) But I need `to be able to find later`, find by id, so, result must be a Relation, not array

Comment: `Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('projects.user_id = ? OR comment_id IS NULL', user.id)` this query doesnt include attachments without comment, why?

Comment: Why this `Attachment.where('comment_id IS NULL')` works, but this `Attachment.joins(comment: [task: [:project]]).where('comment_id IS NULL')` not?

Comment: @fanta , what you think?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. When you use `joins` like that, Rails performs a full join, so, you will never get attachments with no comments. For that you need to perform a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, it works))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fanta

```
class AttachmentPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      # user can see his attachments and attachments without owner
      Attachment
        .left_outer_joins(comment: [task: [:project]])
        .where('projects.user_id = ? OR comment_id IS NULL', user.id)
    end
  end

  def update?
    # if attachment doesnt have owner - anyone can change it
    record.comment.nil? ? true : owner?
  end
end
```